# How to include .jar in Ionic 3 or print in Apex2

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How can I include a .jar in an ionic 3 project? 
This .jar is for printing on a printer Datamax O'neil Apex 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the functionality of a Jar (hopefully a jar that is written for Android, because not all Java code is going to run on Android, especially something that is going to drive a printer, and most Android libraries are kept in .aar not .jar's) you are going to have to write a [Cordova Plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/).  Of course this is only going to work on Android, as iOS uses pod's (CocoaPods) if it is going to work at all.  Ionic, btw, is a wrapper around [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org) which is what you want to look at when the functionality you need is not included in Ionic.